# absolute position child div max-width not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am facing a typical situation. I am trying to practice dropdown menu in CSS. Here, the child div `.dropdown` (grey colored) appears whenever the parent div `.content-small` (green colored) is hovered upon. Please note, that I have used the `.max-width` property for all div's because I want all the div's to scale down/up whenever the browser window is scaled.

Now, what I want to do is that I want to increase the max-width of the child div `dropdown`. But whenever I try to enter a value above 50px, nothing happens. The width DOES NOT increases.

I know that this can be resolved by replacing `max-width` with only `width` in the `.dropdown` class. But if I do that, then the child div `dropdown` will not scale with the browser window. So in any case, I have to use `.max-width` property for all divs.

I also don't want to use media queries at this stage. In totality, this is what I am looking for:

1. I want to increase the width of the dropdown child div `.dropdown`, I also want it to be scaled along with the browser windows like all other div's (max-width)
2. I don't want to use media queries at this stage, since I am trying to practice with plain CSS
3. I don't mind if the `.dropdown` div DOES NOT remain the child of the parent `.content-small` (if  a possible solution needs it that way)

Would appreciate a solution for this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  text-decoration: none;  
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,255,1); 
}

html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  top: 5px;
}

.content-small:hover .dropdown{
  visibility: visible; 
}

.dropdown {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(214,214,214,1);
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
  top: 47px;
  left: -3px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-small">
      Home
      <div class="dropdown"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this does not interfere with what you are trying to accomplish, but what about restructuring your code a little bit:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-small">Home</div>
        <div class="container" style="height:60px;padding-top:10px;">
            <div class="dropdown"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

a {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration: none;      
}

a:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,255,1); 
}

html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding: 0px;
    }



.wrapper {
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.content {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    top: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.content-small:hover + .container, .container:hover{
    visibility: visible;    
}
.container{visibility:hidden;display: inline-block;
max-width: 100px;
width: 100%;}

.dropdown {
    background-color: rgba(214,214,214,1);
    border: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
  max-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
top: 5px;
```

}

And here is:
**[UPDATED JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rd8edsff/3/.)**

**[EDIT]**

The `+` in the css select is saying to look for elements after the first criteria. So, in this case, the css is saying, when you hover over `.content-small`, it then targets the element AFTER `.content-small` with `.dropdown` and applies the css to it. Although it is not the most clear, here is a link of some [documentation on css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

**[SECOND EDIT]**

I changed the code above to wrap the `dropdown` in a container and then set it so on `container:hover` it alters the `visibility` of `.dropdown` the same way, making it persist as visible if you are hovering over either. The reason I had to introduce a container is to give it that spacing between `.dropdown` and `.content-small` - which you can see I did with `padding-top:` and not `margin-top:` because `margin` would not have worked with the `:hover`

Comment: That looks good. but it does not works when I set the visibility of `.dropdown` to hidden (so that it pops up whenever the parent div is hovered upon)

Comment: Try changing the css to: `.content-small:hover + .dropdown{
 visibility: visible; 
}`

Comment: yes! That worked Could you please explain how and what the `.content-small:hover + .dropdown{ visibility: visible; }` does?

Comment: added in the answer

Comment: ok, here is the problem now. If I use that above line of code as you suggested, then the moment I quit hovering from the parent div and move my mouse to hover on the dropdown child div, the dropdown child div disappears. so it makes it impossible to click any link on the dropdown child div

Comment: altered the code, updated the fiddle and gave explanation in the answer

Comment: great solution! thanks. would be helpful if you an provide a code with the indovidual list items vertically stacked (just acting as individual dropdown divs) inside the container.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I'm sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: what I am looking for, when I hover on the `.content-small` parent div, it should drop down with the container div wrapping the `.dropdown` div. Now in that `dropdown` div, I want to have `<li>Line1</li> , <li>Line2</li>` dropping down one below each other (all at once). So what I mean is that `li` being converted to dropdown divs!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. You mean to have the `<li>` tags animated? Either way, that sounds like a completely different question and should be posted as such. Unfortunately, the comments section of this question is not the place to talk about that. Feel free to post a new question and I am sure you will find an answer :)

Comment: here, I posted in a new section :[li dropdown query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001999/li-and-parent-div-size-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

when you tell: `width:100%;` to an absolute child, it takes innerwidth and won't mind the borders,*why should it overflow* :) ?

You may size it with coordonates like you did for `left`, use `right` as well and drop the `width:100%;`

`max-width` will still be efficient and you may use `margin:auto` as well if you wish.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 220px;
  /*demo purpose */
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-small {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 204, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  top: 5px;
}
.content-small:hover .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 1);
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  top: 47px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
.wrapper + .wrapper .dropdown {
  max-width: 50px;
  font-size:0.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-small">
      Home
      <div class="dropdown">100% + border
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-small">
      Home
      <div class="dropdown">tiny
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```