# li and parent div size mismatch

Tags: html, css

practicing on css dropdown. In the following code, I have set the `li` as block display type. Now I want the size of the `li` (the green dropdown ones inside the grey colored parent div `.dropdown`) to be exactly the same horizontal size as of their parent div `.dropdown` . In the current case, their horizontal size is smaller (please see the screenshot below to understand better)

[image]

Kindly please provide a solution.

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding: 0px;
    }


*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

a {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration: none;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); */
 display: block;
}

li {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
 border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}

.dropdown a {
 /* [disabled]color: rgba(0,255,0,1); */
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(204,51,153,1); */
 width: 100%;
}

a:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,255,1); 
}




.wrapper {
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.content {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    top: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.content-small:hover + .dropdown{
    visibility: visible;    
}

.dropdown:hover{
 visibility: visible;
}



.dropdown {
 background-color: rgba(214,214,214,1);
 max-width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 visibility: hidden;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
   <div class="content-small">
  Home
        </div>
   <ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="">Home1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Home2</a></li>
  </div>
     
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Pro-tip: if you need an image, to explain something, then you're doing something wrong on the explaining side.

Comment: Hmm, what could the problem be... `max-height: 200px; max-width: 600px;`

Comment: The answer is just `padding: 0px;` in `.dropdown`. Also you should close your `<ul>` tag

Comment: @Bálint Well that's some harsh advice. Sometimes an image is quite useful in instances that a textual description may not provide the best visualization for an issue and communicates far more effectively...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<ul class="dropdown">` has some default studying for a `<ul>` tag in it, in this case `padding-left:40px;` and then the `height` attribute you gave it. try the following CSS:

```
.dropdown {
padding-left:0;
height:initial;
}
```

You can also just remove the `height` attribute

Answer (score 4):

Adding `padding:0` to your dropdown `<ul>`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding: 0px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); */
  display: block;
}
li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.dropdown a {
  /* [disabled]color: rgba(0,255,0,1); */
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(204,51,153,1); */
  width: 100%;
}
a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-small {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 204, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  top: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.content-small:hover + .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown {
  background-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 1);
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-small">
      Home
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Home1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home2</a>
      </li>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

The gray below the list items comes from the height you set on the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a  CSS reset for margins and/or padding?  The UL is one of the HTML elements that has margins applied in the default browser CSS.

For a quick fix try:

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```